# Where to put create model and association logic in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, model

I have a model `A` with some association to `B` via a join table `AB`. In the `create` action for the `A` controller I create the join model if the optional params are present for the association, otherwise only `A` is created without the `AB` association.

If I leave all the logic in the controller then the controller gets pretty fat and a pain to test and the logic cannot be re-used easily. If I try to move the logic to the model `A` then I just have a random method for `create_with_AB` or something similar. It doesn't feel right.

It feels like there should be some layer in between? I'm not sure if there is a common pattern used to handle a situation like this?

Comment: Are you aware of [nested attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example does not seem very complex and can be done using [nested attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) as mentioned in the comment. For more complex stuff, there is nothing provided by the framework and you have to come up with your own abstraction.

Have a look at `service objects`:

1. https://www.engineyard.com/blog/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services
2. https://medium.com/selleo/essential-rubyonrails-patterns-part-1-service-objects-1af9f9573ca1

Again since these are community abstractions, there is no standard way of implementing service objects - some people use classes with call method, some use modules, etc. How you use them depends on your definition of clean code.